# How can an integer be factorized as n*m so that n^m has the highest value. 

Tags: factorization

Given an integer d, is there a way of finding max(n^m), where d=n*m, except brute-forcing it ?
n and m don't have to be primes.

For example:

The number 12 can be factorized into two factors as: 1*12, 2*6, 3*4, 4*3, 6*2 and 12*1.
Raising the first factor to the second gives: 1, 64, 81, 64, 36 and 12.
The maximum value is 81.

Comment: This is not really a research-level question, I think. But anyway, a hint is that you're looking to maximize $n^{d/n} = (n^{1/n})^d$. So try to maximize $n^{1/n}$ over divisors of $d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n$ is divisible by three than the required split is $(3,n/3)$. If $n$ is not divisible by 3 then the required split is $(p,n/p)$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $n$.

Comment: Simpler: it's always $(p,n/p)$ where $p$ is the prime divisor of $n$ closest to $3$. 

Comment: Less simple but closer to the computation: It's the prime divisor closest to $e$.